# issue with the code to download without download box in Firefox using selenium?

Tags: java, firefox, pdf, selenium

```
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf,application/x-pdf");
```

I am using above code MIME of pdf is i think correct `application/pdf,application/x-pdf` and then using this to

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.navigate().to("Website");
```

but I am unable to understand the problem with My code because the firefox still show the dialogue box

[image: ScreenShot from my computer]

Comment: and I'm unable to understand YOUR problem. what's the question?

Comment: @TwelveDollar Its not working. firefox still show the diloge box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

Comment: Reproduced the issue and setting `pdfjs.disabled` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

try to set MIME type to:

```
application/octet-stream
```

Comment: added it to browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk?

Comment: Yes. I have added their.

Comment: strange. why not using HTTP requests to download file instead of Selenium? not made for it anyway

Comment: because first I have to upload a file and I am working on larger framework.